In the delayed choice quantum eraser experiment, is an interference pattern in the eraser subset always detected or is it just statistically likely?
I understand that in the delayed choice quantum eraser experiment an interference pattern of signal photons is never observed at detector $D_0$  overall (see attached diagram). However, an interference pattern is observed if you consider only the subset of signal photons whose corresponding idler photons ended up in the eraser condition, which according to my understanding is random (which path information erased vs not erased).

My question is, does this interference pattern always emerge or is it statistically very likely?
If the answer is always:
i) Suppose I select a set A of signal photos that together don't form an interference pattern and let's call the set of their corresponding idler photons B. If the decision whether to erase which path information of each idler photon is really random, it would be possible that by chance (even if the probability is very low) the set of idler photons whose which path information is erased ends up being exactly set B. Now by construction set A does not show an interference pattern. Does that mean the choice to remove/keep which path information is not really random?
ii) If I deliberately choose to remove which path information only of set B, again the corresponding signal photons will by construction not show an interference pattern. Is that because the results only hold if the choice is random and not influenced by any information coming from signal photons?

The DCQE has kind of been debunked ... see Wikipedia.  There is no FTL.  "Interference" in the DCQE (as in the DSE) is basically the EM field guiding energy (photons) ... an excited electron in the source is already influencing the field even before the photon is emitted.  The EM field sees all the electrons in the apparatus.

The pattern itself is a statistical pattern.  The data collection is a set of positions, and the interference pattern is a distribution  across those positions.
That being said, via the law of big numbers, the probability that we can confidently reject non-interference patterns goes up as the number of samples go up.  As the number of points goes up, one's confidence that one is sampling an interference pattern goes up.
